# Name 'variable_name' used both as a parameter and as a global. How to fix?

Tags: python

The code I am working with is

```
build_data = {}

# Code that adds data to build_data

build_data_filtered = {}
if flag:

    # Code that adds subset of build_data to build_data_filtered

    global build_data
    build_data = build_data_filtered
```

The line "global build_data" shows a code hint in pycharm

```
Name 'build_data' used both as a parameter and as a global
```

What can I do to remove this hint or is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using the `global` statement outside of a function?

Just remove the line `global build_data` and this should work.

Comment: Interesting. Thats what I had initially done. It was showing a hint "Variable build_data unused". But it does seem to work. Thanks!